# jQuery image fader slow in IE6 & 7

Tags: jquery

I'm using the following jQuery script to rotate through a series of images pulled into an unordered list using PHP:

```
function theRotator() {
    $('#rotator li').css({opacity: 0.0});
    $('#rotator li:first').css({opacity: 1.0});
    setInterval('rotate()',5000);
};

function rotate() { 
    var current = ($('#rotator li.show') ?  $('#rotator li.show') : $('#rotator li:first'));
    var next = ((current.next().length) ? ((current.next().hasClass('show')) ? $('#rotator li:first') :current.next()) : $('#rotator li:first'));   
    next.css({opacity: 0.0}).addClass('show').animate({opacity: 1.0}, 2000);
    current.animate({opacity: 0.0}, 2000).removeClass('show');
};

$(document).ready(function() {      
    theRotator();
});
```

It works brilliantly in FF, Safari, Chrome and even IE8 but IE6 & 7 are really slow. Can anyone make any suggestions on making it more efficient or just work better in IE6 & 7?

The script is from [here](http://www.alohatechsupport.net/webdesignmaui/maui-web-site-design/easy_jquery_auto_image_rotator.html) btw. Thanks.

Comment: Jamie, Is your images coming out correctly?? I used the same in my site and the images gets clipped in IE

Comment: They are displayed fine, just need to make sure the width and height are specified for it to work in IE. You can see it here: http://callaghan-interiors.co.uk/

Answer (score 0):

Hey Jamie, Just remember that IE6+7 don't use the same Javascript parsers as real browsers (It's a joke!) FF Chrome & Safari all have prioritized faster javascript execution in recent versions, whereas IE may show performance in IE9 (I hope they do myself.) Also realize this slideshow will run slow in mobile devices, etc. It's not that you're doing anything wrong persay, just that JS is handled differently in different places.

Comment: Thanks Kyle, I'm aware of the issues with IE's JS execution, I was just wondering if anyone could suggest any optimisation to get it working better. I'm now wondering if the size of the images makes much of a difference as the demo of the script (linked in my original post) works better in IE.

As for mobile devices, it works perfectly on my iPhone but I haven't tested anywhere else.